# If don't aspire to be a general cannot be a simple soldier

Tags: sources-mekorot, army-military-war, quotations, avodath-hashem

I believe I read this saying (originally said by Napoleon) by one of the Gedolim (Torah leaders) with respect to one's religious service. Could be it was the Chafetz Chaim. Looking for a source.

The idea I believe is that if one does not aspire to great heights in his service of God, then he cannot even be a simple God fearing Jew.

I found a related idea in [Tana d'Bei Eliyahu (ch.25)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tanna_Debei_Eliyahu_Rabbah.25.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "one should always tell himself when will my deeds approach those of my forefathers Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob", but nothing like the above.

Comment: Alter Rebbe, maybe? He often talked about Napoleon, as well as the other Lubavitcher rebbes after him. See here: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1155/jewish/Bonaparte-and-the-Chassid.htm

Comment: I understood the idea the opposite way - that even if you do not believe you can be an outstanding gadol yourself (you cannot become a general) at least you can be a loyal soldier (do your best). The idea is not be be depressed that you may not achieve as much as others in serving God.

Answer (score 9):

This saying is quoted in the name of the Chafetz Chaim on multiple websites:

[Here's](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/6344) a video in which Rabbi Ovadyah Yosef zt"l says it in his name (from 19:14). And the story is likewise told in [this book](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=54482&st=&pgnum=19&hilite=) about Rav Ovadyah's sayings and in [this article](https://www.srugim.co.il/135220-%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93-%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9A) by Rabbi Shlomo Aviner. His version is thus:

> "פעם נכנס החפץ חיים לישיבת ראדין, כולם תלמידי חכמים, הטו אזנם לשמוע. רבותי! אומר לכם מעשה: נפוליאון, זה היה מצביא גדול של צרפת, היה קיסר של צרפת. נפוליאון פעם אחת עשה מסדר עם החיילים שלו. עמד ואמר כך: חיילים, תשמעו! כל מי שאינו שואף להיות גנרל - אין מקומו פה, שילך, הוא גם לא חייל. חייל זה רק לשאוף, לעלות, להתקדם, מחיל אל חיל עד שיהיה גנרל. ואני אומר לכם רבותי! מי שלא שואף להיות גדול הדור - שילך מכאן, אין מקומו כאן."

Translation: "One day the Chafetz Chaim entered the yeshiva in Radin, all of them [the students] were talmidei chachamim, and they turned to listen. "Gentlemen! I shall tell you a story: Napoleon, he was a great general of France; he was the emperor of France. Napoleon once organized a line-up of his soldiers. He stood and said: "Soldiers, Listen! Whoever doesn't aspire to be a general - his place is not here, he should go, he won't even be a simple soldier. Being a soldier means aspiring to rise, to move forward, from rank to rank until he becomes a general." And I say to you gentlemen! Whoever doesn't aspire to be the Gedol Hador - he should leave, his place is not here."

[Here](https://he-il.facebook.com/B613B/posts/731275026887476) and [here](http://www.acheinu.co.il/?p=1159) it's said that the story came from the book Olat Shlomo part 2, pg. 501. There's [such a book](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/20997) on Hebrewbooks, but the quote doesn't appear to be in it (nor does it have 501 pages), so presumably it's a different Olat Shlomo.

[Most of the following sources can be found on Otzar Hachochmah and a couple also on Hebrewbooks (as linked)]

Here are several more sources that trace the quote to the Chafetz Chaim:

In the book Vayehi Binso'ah Ha'aron in memory of Rabbi Avraham Shapira, pg. 63, it's also brought in the name of the Chafetz Chaim. In the book [Yalkut Avrech](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=86&book=617004) by R' Avraham Kohen, he quotes the book Meir Einei Yisrael where it says that the author heard from "a famous talmid chacham" who heard from [Rabbi Eliyahu Duschnitzer](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A8) who heard said he heard it from the Chafetz Chaim. Rabbi Duschnitzer was a student of the Chafetz Chaim and later a rabbi in his yeshiva in Radin. Rabbi Abba Kleinerman in [Kovetz Gilyonot 5778 Vakyikra 3](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=378&book=629722) wrote that he heard from [Rabbi Yechezkel Sarna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechezkel_Sarna), a student of the Saba of Slobodka, that the Chafetz Chaim would say this.

And here are several sources that trace it to other rabbis:

In Imrei Shefer on Pirkei Avot by Rabbi Shmuel Pinchasi, it is brought in the name of the Saba of Slobodka ([pg. 158](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=158&book=50686)). [Rabbi Yosef Kanwitz](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A5)'s son also brings it in the name of the Saba, in the book about his father, [Divrei Yosef, pg. 3](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=5&book=157367). So too in the publication of the Youths of Agudat Yisrael [Diglenu, Issue 339](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=6&book=193310). In the book [Bnei Chayil](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=426&book=612707) by R' Gold it is brought in the name of Rabbi Akiva Eiger. [Rabbi Yehudah Segal](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%92%D7%9C) in [Dorshei Hashem](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=40&book=625890) and in [Reshit Ha'avodah](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=37&book=148679) brings it in the name of [Rabbi Eliyahu Duschnitzer](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A8), similar to what was brought, above, in Meor Einei Yisrael, although he doesn't trace it further back to the Chafetz Chaim. In [Nazar Hayah Shmuel, pg. 72](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=56855&st=&pgnum=72), it is said in the name of [Rabbi Moshe Sholzinger](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%A8#%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95) that Rabbi Yisrael of Salant said this.

---

A note on the quote: After some digging, it turns out that this phrase was wrongly attributed to Napoleon. According to Gilles Henry, Petit dictionnaire des expressions nées de l’Histoire, p. 62, It actually originates in the following statement made by [Louis XVIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_XVIII) in 1819 during a visit to the [École polytechnique school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_polytechnique), which had been a military school during the time of Napoleon but was removed from this status by Louis XVIII. This is what he said:

> "Rappelez-vous qu’il n’es aucun de vous qui n’ait dans sa giberne le bâton de maréchal du duc de Reggio; c’est à vous de l’en faire sortir."

Which means: "Remember that there is not one of you who does not have the Duke of Reggio's marshal's baton in your pouch; it's up to you to get it out."

Which means the same thing as the later expression, i.e. that everyone should strive to be great.

The full entry from Henry's book can be read [here](https://www.historia.fr/le-mot-juste/avoir-son-b%C3%A2ton-de-mar%C3%A9chal).

[This 1890 card](https://www.akg-images.fr/archive/Chaque-soldat-a-son-baton-de-Marechal-dans-sa-giberne-2UMDHUWL79Y_D.html) also brings it in the name of Louis XVIII, although dates the quote to an 1817 military law discussion of some sort.

Comment: Hard to imagine that Napoleon said any such thing.

Comment: @MichoelR I found it quoted on a few secular sites such as [here](https://search.yahoo.com/search?fr=mcafee&type=E210US91105G91419&p=A+bad+soldier+is+the+one+who+doesn%27t+aspire+to+be+a+general.+If+you+don%27t+have+any+aspirations%2C+you+might+die+a+corporal+or+a+private.) and [here](https://specialties.bayt.com/en/specialties/q/113933/says-napoleon-the-soldier-who-don-t-aspire-to-or-after-the-general-of-last-resort-it-do-you-have-a-talent-for-leadership/) and [here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/NapoleonsFamousProverb/qnjn/post.htm) but yeah, doesn't prove anything

Comment: probably best to ask on Skeptics.SE or History.SE.

Comment: I just think that it makes good sense for an eved Hashem (depending on what a "general' is), but perhaps no sense at all for a soldier. Plenty of good soldiers want to get through their term alive and I can't imagine that Napoleon would discourage them.

Comment: @MichoelR I think it was suppose to be the opposite - he was trying to encourage them. When I was in basic training in the IDF, whenever our sergeants would ask for a volunteer and only a couple of guys would raise their hands, they would yell at us that "What don't you understand? When we ask for a volunteer, everyone must raise their hand!" - it sounds awfully ridiculous because it makes the word "volunteer" meaningless, but that's the way officers encourage people into getting more into a militaristic head. And it's true that a soldier who doesn't have any aspirations -

Comment: even to just be a good soldier, is no use at all.

Comment: "Volunteer?" "I enlisted, Sergeant; that's it for the duration."

Comment: @MichoelR :D I wasn't one of the wise-guys. I'm sure one of them did say something of the sort at one point, but I don't remember.

Comment: the quote by Louis XVIII is very different. it just means everyone has the potential to be great but not that one must aspire to greatness to advance